# SwiftUI toggles not changing value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, toggle

I'm trying to implement a filter view, however, the `Toggles` are not working.

This is my code:

```
struct FilterDropdown: View {
    
    @State private var A = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                HStack {
                    Text("A")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .bold()
                    Spacer()
                }
                Toggle(isOn:$A) {
                    Text("A")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
            }
            
            Group {
                HStack {
                    Text("To Do")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .bold()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.init(red: 211/255, green: 211/255, blue: 213/255))
            }
            
            Group {
                HStack {
                    Text("Transport")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .bold()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.init(red: 211/255, green: 211/255, blue: 213/255))
                
                TransportTypeToggles()
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, opacity: 1))
    }
}

struct TransportTypeToggles: View {
    @State private var A = false
    @State private var B = false
    @State private var C = false
    @State private var D = false
    @State private var E = false
    @State private var F = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn:$A) {
            Text("A")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        }
        
        Toggle(isOn: $B) {
            Text("B")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        }
        
        Toggle(isOn: $C) {
            Text("C")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        }
        
        Toggle(isOn: $D) {
            Text("D")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        }
        
        Toggle(isOn: $E) {
            Text("E")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        }
        
        Toggle(isOn: $F) {
            Text("F")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        }
        .disabled(true)
        
        Toggle(isOn: $G) {
            Text("G")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        }
        .disabled(true)
    }
}
```

If I place the `Toggles` inside a `List` they work, however, this is not the interface I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you prepare minimal reproducible example? Provided code is not testable.

Comment: I'm commuting right now. When I get home I will replace those vars with `State` vars and it will work. Thanks

Comment: Then the problem is not in the provided code, but in your ObservableObject classes.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. I will change it. I meant that I will replace those observed vars with state vars.

Comment: @Asperi you should be able to reproduce it now. Thank you!

Comment: in TransportTypeToggles, you have to put Toggles embedded in a VStack